# How do I start Hunchentoot?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, hunchentoot

How do I start Hunchentoot on a project? I looked over Edi Weitz's guide and everything went smoothly until after installation. The listed tutorials were either broken or skimmed over actual server usage.

I have my asdf file, installed dependencies with quicklisp, and set up a dispatch table. How do I get Hunchentoot to work with this stuff?

Comment: http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/#start like so?

Answer (score 3):

To update, I've improved upon Svante's answer:

```
(defun start-server ()
  (stop-server)
  (start (setf *acceptor*
               (make-instance 'easy-acceptor
                              :port 4242))))

(defun stop-server ()
  (when *acceptor*
    (when started-p *acceptor*
     (stop *acceptor*))))
```

Prior to starting the server, *acceptor* is nil. After the server has been started (even if it has subsequently been stopped) it is no longer nil. The started-p test checks to see if an initialized easy-acceptor is started. If you try to stop an already stopped acceptor, you receive an error.

Answer (score 2):

You invoke `start` on an instance of an `acceptor`.

If you use the basic `easy-handler` mechanism that comes with hunchentoot, that would be an `easy-acceptor`.

You will want to have a mechanism in place to start and stop your server.  That might look like this:

```
(defvar *acceptor* nil)

(defun start-server ()
  (stop-server)
  (start (setf *acceptor*
               (make-instance 'easy-acceptor
                              :port 4242))))

(defun stop-server ()
  (when *acceptor*
    (stop *acceptor*)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(start (defparameter hunchentoot-listener
         (make-instance 'easy-acceptor
                        :port 4242
                        :document-root #p"/path/to/your/html/")))
```

will get you a running web server on port 4242 (http://localhost:4242/)

Comment: Don't use `defparameter` like that.  You want your toplevel forms to be reloadable.

Comment: I'm still on the up slope of the learning curve - can you give an example of a more acceptable way?

Comment: I added an example to my answer.